# Record Audio Permission is not displayed in my Application on starting the Application

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have added

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
```

In Manifest.

In Activity after checking Permission is not granted I am requesting

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
```

On Starting of Application.
Storage Permission is shown but Audio Record Permission is not shown.
Not displayed even in Application ->  Permission.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: all permissions in the manifest doesnot require the user to allow... for eg... internet permission, bluetooth permission etc etc....

Comment: if the user allows the storage permission and the dev writes the record audio permission in the manifest.. it will automatically enable it.. you dont have to worry about it..

Comment: Dear  @Santanu Sur,
I am testing my Application. Popup is not showing for Record Audio, even though I have mentioned that in the requestPermissions.

Comment: When you put permissions in Manifest the user agrees to grant permissions during the installation, therefore there is nothing such as a popup message asking for permissions. However in the latest Android like Nougat and Oreo in some apps there is a popup asking permissions to access photos, audio etc. Where did you test it? On real device?

Comment: Yes, Pixel 2 and LG G6. Failed in both.

Comment: every permission in the manifest doesnot popup **(allow or cancel)**

Comment: But In Log Permission is coming as Denied (-1) for record Audio without User Permission. It is a _Dangerous Permission_ without user agree it will not work.

Comment: I have the same issue Have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 8):

First do `checkSelfPermission`.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
}
```

In Android manifest change:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: if (!checkPermission()) {
                requestPermission();
            }
I had done that. but still user was never asked permission to allow Record Audio. Nor it is shown in Permission list.

Comment: @SudeepMukherjee Also don't forget `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {`

Comment: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
I have covered that part my Activity before checking permission

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my intermediate was not removed, so Clean Build was not happening. Once it was done my code is working as expected.